# Rank of matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-rank

Let $ A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C}) $ so that $ rank(4I_{n} + 5A) \leq rank(2I_{n} + 3A) $.

Prove that $ rank(2I_{n} + 3A) \geq 1 + [\frac{n}{2}]$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697695/matrices-rank-inequality/1697807#1697807, where the OP was able to copy the exercise correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct. Consider
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}-\frac 4 5 & 0\\0 & -\frac 2 3\end{pmatrix}.
$$